# Proxy setting via environmental variables to deploy React app on an AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch-api

I am trying to create a React frontend to an Express API. The two are launched from an AWS EC2, in two different ports. This gives rise to the INVALID HOST HEADER ERROR appearing in the browser, reading around I understand that this is caused by CORS problems.

Setting a PROXY=http://myserver:3001 in the package.json file leads to the same error.

Reading up online I found that this can be done via setting up a proxy in the .env file. However, when creating a .env file in the project root folder containing just the string  REACT_APP_APP_BACKEND_BASEURL=http://myserver:3001 and launching npm start, the INVALID HOST HEADER persists.

So I am wondering, is there anything to be changed in the App.js or in the package.json?

The React app is a simple

```
import React from 'react';

function App() {
fetch(process.env.REACT_APP_BASE_URL)
.then(res => res.json())
.then(res => console.log(res))

}

export default App
```

I am looking to solve this without using any middleware.

Comment: how are you starting / serving your react application on AWS?

Comment: INVALID HOST HEADER ERROR isn’t caused by a CORS problem. That error has nothing to do with CORS.

Comment: I am using create-react-app and starting the application via npm start

Comment: @Antonio that's your problem there I think, `npm start` is running a development server with webpack. instead you want to be building your application using `npm run build` and then serving that build folder contents somehow (serve / nginx) etc